# RewriteEngine adjusting Action php-cgi

Tags: .htaccess

I'm not good with .htaccess stuff at all, our client installed his server and he needed to add this to the .htaccess in order to make the php execute

```
Action php-cgi /~devoaas1/cgi-bin/.ht_bin/php5.cgi 
addHandler php-cgi .php
```

But this seems to give some problems when I turn on the RewriteEngine, I'm not sure how to explain, but it's a problem.

Is there a way to create an ignore rule for the Action php-cgi?

Comment: Please specify the problem you are facing..

Comment: @thinkingMonkey, Sorry, it's rather hard to explain, so when i turn on the RewriteEngine, i'm getting a server error saying that /~devoaas1/cgi-bin/.ht_bin/php5.cgi  could not be found, so i'm thinking that somehow the rewriteengine is affection the url to that path

Comment: please post the error log and the mod_rewrite directives you have used?

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey Unfortunately I don't have access to the logs, this is my .htaccess, it's the same as any Drupal installation, except the 2 lines on the top. http://pastebin.com/HjcUsJ9z    When I comment out RewriteEngine on, everything works (without url rewriting)

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey, I think I figured out what the problem was, RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F] this rule is preventing direct access to directories that start with a "." and since .ht_bin applies to this rule it won't work.

Comment: good to know it worked out. Sorry I couldn't take a look the problem. +1 to your question for solving it.